# Creating a ratio between variables in a Stacked dataframe grouped by some Columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multiple-columns, group-concat

I have a df as follows:

```
df_in 
      G1    G2       TPE           QC
      
      A     S1       td            2
      A     S1       ts            4
      A     S2       td            6
      A     S2       ts            3
      B     S1       td            20
      B     S1       ts            40
      B     S2       td            60
      B     S2       ts            30
      C     S1       td            90
      D     S2       ts            7
```

So the output should be grouped by Columns G1 & G2 and for each such group, do a row wise ratio for the
column QC like (ts/td) where values are td and ts for the column TPE and rename the new variable in column TPE as
ratio. It should also contain the original rows as it is. Also it should be noted that for the TPE column some groups may not have
both ts and td values. In such cases there will be no ratio or the ratio should be kept as blank.

So the output should be this:

```
       df_out


         G1    G2       TPE           QC
      
         A     S1       td            2
         A     S1       ts            4
         A     S2       td            6
         A     S2       ts            3
         B     S1       td            20
         B     S1       ts            40
         B     S2       td            60
         B     S2       ts            30
         C     S1       td            90
         D     S2       ts            7
         A     S1       ratio         2
         A     S2       ratio         0.5
         B     S1       ratio         2
         B     S2       ratio        0.5
         C     S1       ratio         
         D     S2       ratio
```

I tried the following, but its omitting the blank values for group C & D with blank ratios:

```
def calculate_ratio(group):
    td_row = group[group['TPE'] == 'td']
    ts_row = group[group['TPE'] == 'ts']
    if not td_row.empty and not ts_row.empty:
        ratio = ts_row['QC'].values[0] / td_row['QC'].values[0]
        return pd.DataFrame({'G1': [group['G1'].iloc[0]], 
                             'G2': [group['G2'].iloc[0]], 
                             'TPE': ['ratio'], 
                             'QC': [ratio]})
    return pd.DataFrame()


grouped = df_in.groupby(['G1', 'G2']).apply(calculate_ratio).reset_index(drop=True)

df_out = pd.concat([df_in, grouped], ignore_index=True)
```

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
tmp = df_in.set_index(['G1', 'G2', 'TPE']).unstack()['QC']
out = pd.concat([df_in, tmp['ts'].div(tmp['td']).reset_index(name='QC').assign(TPE='ratio')])
```

out:

```
    G1  G2  TPE     QC
0   A   S1  td      2.0
1   A   S1  ts      4.0
2   A   S2  td      6.0
3   A   S2  ts      3.0
4   B   S1  td      20.0
5   B   S1  ts      40.0
6   B   S2  td      60.0
7   B   S2  ts      30.0
8   C   S1  td      90.0
9   D   S2  ts      7.0
0   A   S1  ratio   2.0
1   A   S2  ratio   0.5
2   B   S1  ratio   2.0
3   B   S2  ratio   0.5
4   C   S1  ratio   NaN
5   D   S2  ratio   NaN
```

**Intermedate**

tmp:

```
    TPE td      ts
G1  G2      
A   S1  2.0     4.0
    S2  6.0     3.0
B   S1  20.0    40.0
    S2  60.0    30.0
C   S1  90.0    NaN
D   S2  NaN     7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, which uses multi-indexing, [`pandas.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)
to separate the `ts` values from the `td` ones, and finally uses [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate the two dataframes:

```
s = df.set_index(['G1', 'G2', 'TPE'])

pd.concat([
    df, s.xs('ts', level=2).div(s.xs('td', level=2))
    .reset_index().assign(TPE='ratio')])
```

Output:

```
  G1  G2    TPE    QC
0  A  S1     td   2.0
1  A  S1     ts   4.0
2  A  S2     td   6.0
3  A  S2     ts   3.0
4  B  S1     td  20.0
5  B  S1     ts  40.0
6  B  S2     td  60.0
7  B  S2     ts  30.0
8  C  S1     td  90.0
9  D  S2     ts   7.0
0  A  S1  ratio   2.0
1  A  S2  ratio   0.5
2  B  S1  ratio   2.0
3  B  S2  ratio   0.5
4  C  S1  ratio   NaN
5  D  S2  ratio   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to do this as a one-liner:

```py
out = pd.concat([
    df_in, 
    df_in.pivot(index=['G1','G2'], columns='TPE', values='QC')
         .pipe(lambda df:df['ts'].div(df['td']))
         .reset_index(name='QC')
         .assign(TPE='ratio')
    ]
)
```

Output:

```
  G1  G2    TPE    QC
0  A  S1     td   2.0
1  A  S1     ts   4.0
2  A  S2     td   6.0
3  A  S2     ts   3.0
4  B  S1     td  20.0
5  B  S1     ts  40.0
6  B  S2     td  60.0
7  B  S2     ts  30.0
8  C  S1     td  90.0
9  D  S2     ts   7.0
0  A  S1  ratio   2.0
1  A  S2  ratio   0.5
2  B  S1  ratio   2.0
3  B  S2  ratio   0.5
4  C  S1  ratio   NaN
5  D  S2  ratio   NaN
```

You can add a `fillna('')` to the result if you want the `NaN` values to be empty strings rather than `NaN`.